# How to replace value of a string which is on right side after a space

Tags: string

I am wondering is there any way to replace this type of value in string

```
https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4796/39790122335_bdc207b259_o.jpg https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4776/39790122225_c8e96339fa.jpg
```

What i want is that replace the right side of URL and just show the left side there is little space between them.

Comment: Which language are you using? Javascript, Java, C#, etc ...

Comment: Java@gil.fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in many different ways, using many different languages.

For example, this is how you can do it with JavaScript

```js
var str = 'https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4796/39790122335_bdc207b259_o.jpg https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4776/39790122225_c8e96339fa.jpg'

str = str.split(' ')
str = str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be easily done using the split function.

First assign the url to a Variable

## Python

theurl = 'https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4796/39790122335_bdc207b259_o.jpg https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4776/39790122225_c8e96339fa.jpg'

each_url = theurl.split()

now your new variable each url is a list of objects containing all the URLS

i.e each_url = ['https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4796/39790122335_bdc207b259_o.jpg ', 'https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4776/39790122225_c8e96339fa.jpg']

the Split function works in pretty different Programming Languages

though in some like Javascript you might have to specify split as split(' ')

showing you are splitting by spaces